# Provide same object for all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am retrieving data via a rest-service and **store them in an object**. There are also some functions on the page to drill-down later. 
Now I thought, since this data will barely change and need about 10 seconds to load, I would like to store them and **use the same object on every request**. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-Memory Caching solved my problem since it works with complex objects, too.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    // configure other services
}
```

---

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public IndexModel(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
var cacheEntry = DateTime.Now;
_cache.Set("Time", cacheEntry);
```

---

```
var myEntry = _cache.Get<DateTime>("myKey");
```